# Unreadable GeoJSON file in QGIS fixed by trivial reordering

Tags: qgis, geojson

I'm having a problem reading a GeoJSON file in QGIS.
The file can be found at [this git repository](https://github.com/icepack/icepack-data/blob/master/meshes/larsen/larsen_inflow.geojson).
When I try to load in the file, I get an error message that it's invalid, but the "Reason:" field is empty.
However, when I trivially reorder the fields under "geometry" to put

```
"type": "LineString"
```

at the start instead of at the end, QGIS can load it.
The fixed version of the GeoJSON file is [here](https://github.com/icepack/icepack-data/blob/larsen-inflow/meshes/larsen/larsen_inflow.geojson).
As far as I understand, the ordering of keys in a JSON object is completely immaterial, so I don't see why this change should make a difference.
I'm able to read both files just fine in the web version of ArcGIS.
Is this a problem with the GeoJSON file or have I found a bug in QGIS?

Comment: For original file, not able to reproduce using QGIS 3.6.2-Noosa on Ubuntu 18.04 64 bits as it works. => Version of QGIS you are using?

Comment: I'm using 3.6 but I've had this going back to older version, I'll try upgrading to 3.6.2.

Comment: @user2856 please make that an answer rather than comment

Comment: Yes @user2856 please make that an answer and I'll accept. Thanks to your suggestion I've been able to reproduce the problem with gdal-2.3.2, 2.4.1, and 3.0, but I have no problem on gdal-2.1.4.

Comment: The problem is somehow related to crs. If I remove the whole crs member then GDAL 2.5-dev reads the json file without other edits.

Comment: Moving crs after  `"name": "larsen_inflow"` works also and GDAL reads the data, including CRS info. Feels still like a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not QGIS.  It's the underlying GDAL library (I'm running 2.4).

Your 1st geojson fails when read from a file saved to the filesystem.

```
ogrinfo filepath/master/larsen_inflow.geojson # Fail
ogrinfo filepath/larsen-inflow branch/larsen_inflow.geojson  # Success
```

**However**... the 1st geojson can be opened fine when read from a url

```
ogrinfo https://<master>/larsen_inflow.geojson # Success!?!?
ogrinfo https://<larsen-inflow branch>/larsen_inflow.geojson  # Success
```

Smells like a bug to me. Suggest you ask on [GDAL-DEV mailing list](https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/gdal-dev/) or [post an issue](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/) (search for dupes first).

Edit: it's a [bug](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1537) and has been resolved.